# Create order progamatically with all parameter in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database

I am working on data migration from Oracle DB  database to Magento 2 database so I need to create CSV template for getting data in our format.

while creating order, how we can cover all these things such as: store,customer, csvproduct,shipping and payment methods.
I want to create CSV template/single insert query so how I can create order programmatically.

Comment: Try the foloowing blog https://webkul.com/blog/create-quote-and-order-programmatically-in-magento2/

Comment: tried already . its  not match my requirement .